# How do I print my outputs of a for loop in one line ordered by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, indexing, printing

Is it possible to print my outputs of a for loop in one line and ordered by index:
For example:
outputs:TAWSG, HUHWO, ETOHO, RHDAD, EOETI, IRCID, SIISE, NTDAA, OYE
----> THEREISNOAUTHORITYWHODECIDESWHATISAGOODIDEA

Comment: Is the input a list with those strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every possible index `i`, you would print a character from each string of the list. So, for each string `x` in the list you would print out `x[i]` if `x[i]` exists (by checking length of x).

Full Code:

```py
lst = ['TAWSG', 'HUHWO', 'ETOHO', 'RHDAD', 'EOETI', 'IRCID', 'SIISE', 'NTDAA', 'OYE']

max_len = max([len(x) for x in lst ])

for i in range(max_len):
    for x in lst: 
        if len(x) > i:
            print(x[i], end = '')
print('\n')
```

Output:
`THEREISNOAUTHORITYWHODECIDESWHATISAGOODIDEA`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.